# Unable to transform from EPSG:3857 to UTM in Geotools

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I'm using Geotools to perform some transformations between coordinate reference systems. I created a proof of concept taking data from Google Earth, which uses `ESPG:4326`, and converting it to UTM.

The first problem I encountered was identifying the UTM tile to work on. I think this gets solved using the following reference: 
`CRS.decode(String.format("AUTO2:42001,%s,%s", longitude, latitude ), true)`. Where `longitud` and `latitude` are the coordinates of the area I'm working on.

I was able to apply transformations between these two systems:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84= CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem utm=CRS.decode(String.format("AUTO2:42001,%s,%s", -3.691406,  40.403431 ), true);
MathTransform toMeters= CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, utm);
MathTransform toDegrees= CRS.findMathTransform(utm, wgs84);

com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory jtsGf= JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[5];
coordinates[0]=new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855,40.43597099928637);
coordinates[1]=new Coordinate(-3.677717792288855,40.43591469226429);
coordinates[2]=new Coordinate(-3.677605067311292,40.43726977694883);
coordinates[3]=new Coordinate(-3.67914084885543,40.4373645084199);
coordinates[4]=new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855,40.43597099928637);

Geometry mRank = JTS.transform(jtsGf.createPolygon(jtsGf.createLinearRing(coordinates), null), toMeters);
```

When I try to run the same code using `ESPG:3857` instead of `ESPG:4362` I get the following error when trying to apply the transformation:

```
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: The transform result may be 0 meters away from the expected position. Are you sure that the input coordinates are inside this map projection area of validity? The point is located 3°00.0'E away from the central meridian and 0°00.0'N away from the latitude of origin. The projection is "Transverse_Mercator".
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.checkReciprocal(MapProjection.java:708)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:903)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:938)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.ConcatenatedTransformDirect.transform(ConcatenatedTransformDirect.java:81)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:123)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.projectCoordinateSequence(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:295)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformStraightLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:237)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:216)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformPolygon(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:304)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:170)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS.transform(JTS.java:442)
```

The most weird part is `... transform result may be 0 meters away from the expected position...`, which seems the perfect situation for a transformation.

Any clues on what is wrong?

**EDIT: added failing code, stack trace, dependencies, UTM projection and transformation dumps**

The failing code snippet

```
        CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84 = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857 ", true);
    //systema utm para las coordenadas de madrid
    CoordinateReferenceSystem utm = CRS.decode(String.format("AUTO2:42001,%s,%s", -3.691406, 40.403431), true);
    MathTransform toMeters = CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, utm);
    MathTransform toDegrees = CRS.findMathTransform(utm, wgs84);

    com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory jtsGf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[5];
    coordinates[0] = new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855, 40.43597099928637);
    coordinates[1] = new Coordinate(-3.677717792288855, 40.43591469226429);
    coordinates[2] = new Coordinate(-3.677605067311292, 40.43726977694883);
    coordinates[3] = new Coordinate(-3.67914084885543, 40.4373645084199);
    coordinates[4] = new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855, 40.43597099928637);

    Geometry mRank = JTS.transform(jtsGf.createPolygon(jtsGf.createLinearRing(coordinates), null), toMeters);
```

The error stack trace:

```
org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: The transform result may be 0 meters away from the expected position. Are you sure that the input coordinates are inside this map projection area of validity? The point is located 3°00.0'E away from the central meridian and 0°00.0'N away from the latitude of origin. The projection is "Transverse_Mercator".

at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.checkReciprocal(MapProjection.java:708)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:903)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.MapProjection.transform(MapProjection.java:938)
at org.geotools.referencing.operation.transform.ConcatenatedTransformDirect.transform(ConcatenatedTransformDirect.java:81)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(DefaultCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:123)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.projectCoordinateSequence(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:295)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformStraightLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:237)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformLineString(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:216)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transformPolygon(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:304)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.transform(GeometryCoordinateSequenceTransformer.java:170)
at org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS.transform(JTS.java:442)
at com.byteflair.mercury.api.checkin.CheckinServiceTest.checkThatICanTransformAndBufferPolygon(CheckinServiceTest.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
```

My dependencies based on `mvn dependency:list | grep geotools`:

```
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-main:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-api:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

Also tried with version 14.2 with same results

The `wgs84` projection:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
```

The `utm` projection:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Auto UTM", 
GEOGCS["WGS84(DD)", 
DATUM["WGS84", 
SPHEROID["WGS84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]], 
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", -3.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]
```

The `toMeters` transformation:

```
CONCAT_MT[INVERSE_MT[PARAM_MT["Transverse_Mercator", 
PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6356752.314245179], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", -3.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 0.9996], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 500000.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]], 
PARAM_MT["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", 
PARAMETER["semi_major", 6378137.0], 
PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0]]]
```

Comment: Can you dump the wkt of the utm projection into the question please

Comment: @iant just edited the question wit required info

Comment: I don't think that's a utm transform

Comment: @iant that's the output of `utm.toWKT()`. Can you give more clues of what you expect or how to obtain it? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you mixing UTM zone 30 and Michigan Central state plane zone? OH, you've got a mistake in your code somewhere, instead of 3857, you've got 3587, NAD83 (NSRS2007) / Michigan Central.

Comment: Hi @mkennedy, thanks for pointing the mistake in the post. Just edited to add the correct `wsg84` projection and updated the `toMeters' transformation. This mistake has been because of several tests I have done and left the bad value. I just explicitly confirm that with this parameters the error is the one I posted.

Comment: CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84 = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857 ", true); is wrong(ish) in that 3587 is not WGS84 so your coordinates are on [Null Island](http://www.nullisland.com/) (well outside the UTM zone you are using). Look carefully at how my code builds the polygons.

Comment: @iant I'm not sure what I'm missing. When looking to your code you create the polygon and transform it from UTM -> Google Maps -> UTM.  My frontend uses GMaps for input, so I assume the coordinates I get from GMaps are in EPSG:3857 (**assumption**). I need to convert to UTM to make some transient geometric calculations in meters. Then I'm transforming from GMaps CRS to WGS84 and storing the polygon because mongodb uses WGS84 for spatial queries. **Is it that what I'm getting from GMaps are not coordinates in EPSG:3857, as your code implies?** Thanks for your ongoing support!

Comment: Your coordinates are almost certainly in wgs84 lat/lon hence my use of wgs to utm to convert to meters followed by utm to google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to recreate this error, using the following code, which is basically coppied and pasted from the question:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84= CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem google = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857", true);
CoordinateReferenceSystem utm=CRS.decode(String.format("AUTO2:42001,%s,%s", -3.691406,  40.403431 ), true);
MathTransform toMeters= CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, utm);
MathTransform toDegrees= CRS.findMathTransform(utm, wgs84);
MathTransform utmToGoogle = CRS.findMathTransform(utm, google);

com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory jtsGf= JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[5];
coordinates[0]=new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855,40.43597099928637);
coordinates[1]=new Coordinate(-3.677717792288855,40.43591469226429);
coordinates[2]=new Coordinate(-3.677605067311292,40.43726977694883);
coordinates[3]=new Coordinate(-3.67914084885543,40.4373645084199);
coordinates[4]=new Coordinate(-3.679182821543855,40.43597099928637);

Geometry mRank = JTS.transform(jtsGf.createPolygon(jtsGf.createLinearRing(coordinates), null), utmToGoogle);
System.out.println("google"+mRank);
mRank = JTS.transform(jtsGf.createPolygon(jtsGf.createLinearRing(coordinates), null), toDegrees);
System.out.println("wgs84:"+mRank);
```

I get the following answer and no errors (and they both line up if I paste them into QGIS):

```
google POLYGON ((-833646.8252261352 40.59902002387106, -833646.8237650455 40.59896348970921, -833646.8236526242 40.600324038505704, -833646.825184276 40.60041915196819...
wgs84:POLYGON ((-7.488776846583527 0.0003647072020764, -7.488776833458335 0.0003647066942288, -7.488776832448438 0.0003647189162468, -7.488776846207499 0.0003647197706586,...
```

**Update 1**
`mvn dependency:list | grep geotools` gives:

```
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-api:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-coverage:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-cql:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-data:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-epsg-wkt:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-grid:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-main:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-render:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    org.geotools:gt-swing:jar:15-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

**Update2**

I modified the code to try more forward and backward conversions:

```
MathTransform toMeters= CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, utm);
MathTransform toDegrees= CRS.findMathTransform(utm, wgs84);
MathTransform utmToGoogle = CRS.findMathTransform(utm, google);
MathTransform wgsToGoogle = CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84, google);
MathTransform googleToUTM = CRS.findMathTransform(google,utm);
 //[.....create poly as before ...]
Polygon wgsPoly = jtsGf.createPolygon(jtsGf.createLinearRing(coordinates), null);
System.out.println("wgs:"+wgsPoly);

Geometry utmPoly = JTS.transform(wgsPoly, toMeters);
System.out.println("utm:"+utmPoly);
Geometry googlePoly1 = JTS.transform(utmPoly, utmToGoogle);
System.out.println("google1:"+googlePoly1);
Geometry googlePoly2 = JTS.transform(wgsPoly, wgsToGoogle);
System.out.println("google2:"+googlePoly2);
Geometry utmPoly2 = JTS.transform(googlePoly1, googleToUTM);
System.out.println("utm2"+utmPoly2);
```

this gives the following:

```
wgs:POLYGON ((-3.679182821543855 40.43597099928637, -3.677717792288855 40.43591469226429, -3.677605067311292 40.43726977694883...
utm:POLYGON ((442395.32424547715 4476369.013946666, 442519.53321862826 4476361.809516019, 442530.24786807405 4476512.15038715...
google1:POLYGON ((-409564.75822962367 4929500.130541016, -409401.67191895976 4929491.895343309, -409389.1234318578 4929690.085509476,...
google2:POLYGON ((-409564.75822962145 4929500.130541016, -409401.67191895755 4929491.895343313, -409389.1234318556 4929690.085509479...
utm2POLYGON ((442395.32424547547 4476369.013946667, 442519.5332186266 4476361.809516017, 442530.24786807236 4476512.150387148,
```

which seem to agree to within expected tolerances.

Comment: can you post your pom? maybe it's a matter of mixed/clashing dependencies?

Comment: By the way, have you tried transforming from `google` to `utm`. That's the transformation that fails in my code.

Comment: I have posted the final code snippet I'm executing until the instruction in error, the stack trace and my dependencies.The only difference I'm noticing is in the number of dependencies which In the worst case should complain about missing classes but not about a lack of precission. Can you post your `EPSG:3847` to `AUTO:42001` transformation WKT, to see if something differs there?